# Starting Mesibo from a running application

Tags: mesibo

We are creating Mesibo account dynamically after a user finishes its registration. So when we init the Mesibo in a running app, when I click the inbox after initing it, it crashes with session read error.
One thing I thought about using Mesibo.isRead() function to check if the mesibo successfully started but if not how I can handle this situation to wait for it to start?

Answer (score 0):

After you create your mesibo user dynamically, send the user access token back to the user. Once the user has an access token, use it to initialize mesibo, read

https://mesibo.com/documentation/tutorials/get-started/

Also, refer messenger code on GitHub which exactly does as I described above

https://github.com/mesibo/messenger-app-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/mesibo/messenger/SampleAPI.java#L654